# Which design pattern is used in jdbc connection?

Tags: design-patterns, database-connection

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

Which design pattern is in use here ? We see each object returning a different object.

What would be some alternatives to the chosen design pattern ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obviously not every code follows design patterns. But there are still things there that resembles some familiar patterns.

The whole JDBC architecture is actually a [Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern), it is an abstract concept which holds other abstractions that could be replaced separately.

The classes below implements some patterns.

DriverManager.getConnection(URL) seems like a [static factory method](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=21) to me, which is very common in Java frameworks.

Statement and Connection actually follows the same patterns, it is some sort of [Unit of Work or Transaction pattern](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/transaction-patterns.html) since it allows you to bulk statements together. But it also follows a [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) pattern when it implements JDBC Wrapper interface.

ResultSet follows the [Iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) pattern but it is also a [Data mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

**Rectification on the checked answer**:

**The `ResultSet` is not a [*data mapper*](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)**, from whose link we can easily figure out that the concept *data mapper* was coined in the context of *enterprise application architecture* **in 2003**. Whereas the [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) already existed in the late 1990s. One can search for the keyword "since", by means of which one can infer that the earliest version when new features were added is *since 1.2*(in 1998. Refer to [Java version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)), meaning most of the old features such as those *getters* are already in this class before 1998

Class list of JDK 1.1.8 is [here](http://www.ad.ntust.edu.tw/course/ad5601701/jmdl/docs/java/relnotes/classlist.html), where there is already `ResultSet`

Moreover, from the aspect of `DriverManager`, `Connection` and `Driver`, *JDBC* is not only an application of *static factory method* but more precisely **a standard application of *service provider framework*, a design pattern** introduced in **Item 1: consider static factory methods instead of constructors** in the book [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997):

- `Connection` is the *service interface*
- `DriverManager.registerDriver` is the *provider registration* API
- `DriverManager.getConnection` is the *service access API*
- `java.sql.Driver` is the *service provider interface*